how can i tell gsap and js to do something ONLY IF width is above 1200px?
i'm in trouble with a project. I'm trying to create a horizontal scroll with Javascript and GSAP, but only if width is > 1200px. i did a thing and it kinda works, but if i resize the web page to a smaller width it still does the horizontal scroll. srry for my english and please help me!!!
const aboutContainer = document.querySelector(".about__container");
const aboutContent = gsap.utils.toArray(".about__container .about__content");
const aboutMask = document.querySelector(".about__mask");
if (document.body.clientWidth > 1200) {
  let scrollTween = () => {
    gsap.to(aboutContent, {
      xPercent: -100 * (aboutContent.length - 1),
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__container",
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        end: "+=3000",
      },
    });

    gsap.to(aboutMask, {
      width: "100%",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__section",
        start: "top left",
        scrub: 1,
      },
    });

    let tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__container",
        start: "center bottom",
      },
    });

    tl.from(aboutContent, { x: 300, opacity: 0, duration: 1 });
  };
  scrollTween();
};


Hi! I answered your question but turns out I understood you wanted to make the element scrollable when you actually mean you want a 'sliding like animation'. Maybe you could rephrase the question?

Depending on what exactly your goals are, you can use gsap.matchMedia to control at what client size a given set of instructions run, and choose to run them when the browser is resized to the desired width.


const aboutContainer = document.querySelector(".about__container");
const aboutContent = gsap.utils.toArray(".about__container .about__content");
const aboutMask = document.querySelector(".about__mask");

let mm = gsap.matchMedia();

// add a media query. When it matches, the associated function will run
mm.add("(min-width: 800px)", () => {
  let scrollTween = () => {
    gsap.to(aboutContent, {
      xPercent: -100 * (aboutContent.length - 1),
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__container",
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        end: "+=3000",
      },
    });

    gsap.to(aboutMask, {
      width: "100%",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__section",
        start: "top left",
        scrub: 1,
      },
    });

    let tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".about__container",
        start: "center bottom",
      },
    });

    tl.from(aboutContent, { x: 300, opacity: 0, duration: 1 });
  };
  scrollTween();
  return () => {
    // optional cleanup instructions?
  }
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<div class="about__container">
  <div class="about__content">
    About Content
    <div class="about__section">
  </div>
  About Container
</div>
<div class="about__mask">About Mask</div>



boilerplate code for matchMedia from here: https://gsap.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.matchMedia()/

Simple CSS Approach
This might not be the answer you are looking for if you DO NEED to create it using JavaScript and GSAP.
If not: usually, you can achieve that in a more simple way using CSS media queries.
If you want the scroll to only happen when the device width > 1200px I assume the overflow only exists from that point on, so this simple CSS would achieve what you are aiming for.


.container {
/*set containers width to match window/device width*/
width: 100%; 

/*initially hide horizontal overflow in case it exists,*/ 
/*since inherently do not want horizontal scrolling*/
overflow-x: hidden; 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
/*if device's width is >=1200px*/

.container {

/*prevents line breaks -> avoids wrapping*/
/*so that children do not move down*/
white-space: nowrap;

overflow-x: scroll;  /*activate scroll*/
}
<div class="container">
  <div>
This is a child element
  </div>
</div>



I do not think you can resize the output window here so I made a jsFiddle so you can see it in action (I may be mistaken but just to be sure).
There I used a Lorem Ipsum text just to emulate the overflow. Here I removed it to avoid unnecessary scrolling in my answer, since resizing would not be possible anyways.
Code Notes
With this code the scrollbar will appear as soon as the width hits 1200px. If you want it to happen specifically only when >1200px, than just change the 1200px in the media query for 1201px.
Why CSS over JavaScript?
It avoids the overhead that JavaScript solutions might introduce for handling scrolling behavior, especially on larger sites. Which leads to a better performance.
Learn More

You can learn more about the overflow-x property in this mdn web doc.
You can learn more about the white-space property in this mdn web doc.
You can learn more about media queries in this w3Schools doc and in this mdn web doc.


They're creating an animation of the .about__content div sliding in from the right, not making it scrollable or not scrollable. https://jsfiddle.net/xLtma3n6/ though i suspect they certainly could accomplish this goal with css, maybe? doing this with gsap though is pretty common.

That is my bad! I did not check the code, I only read the question and because I understood he needed to make it scrollable I immediately thought on how it is much easier with CSS. I am 100% sure the animation is also possible (and maybe easier?) with CSS. I never worked with gsap though. But maybe it is a school work or something and maybe they do need to use Js and gsap (that is why in my answer I also mentioned it may not be what they are looking for, but maybe it is what someone else is looking for... we never know)

I would honestly be interested in seeing a css version of this specific gcc animation, i'm sure it's possible, i just haven't tried. gsap makes it quite easy, surely it couldn't be too difficult with css? Would be useful to have regardless. My understanding is to do this with CSS you'd need to add a class with javascript to trigger it, but... could media queries do that?

I really like to work with CSS, maybe I will take a more attentive look tomorrow and try it out. I will share it if I achieve it. Let me know if you do the same, always interested in learning more :)
